# How to add constraint one car can only go in one direction in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

- Each employee has a direction in which he works.
- Each car can travel in one direction. If an employee who works in direction `A` was added to the car, then only employees who work in the same direction should be in it

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Employee {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String direction;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "vehicleRange")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

}

@PlanningEntity
public class Vehicle {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "vehicle")
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    private String direction;

}
```

What is the best constraint for this?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. Maybe share your constraint implementation and describe how it behaves.

If you don't know how to start with the ConstraintStreams API, please read the documentation:
https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html

There is also a plethora of examples, nearly each one of them comes with its ConstraintProvider:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I will definitely check out the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.

```java
private Constraint directionConflict(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.forEach(Employee.class)
        .groupBy(Employee::getVehicle)
        .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getEmployees().stream()
            .anyMatch(employee -> !Objects.equals(employee.getDirection(),
                vehicle.getEmployees().get(0).getDirection())))
        .penalize("Direction conflict", HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the car's direction is not builtin but defined by the first passenger, I'd go with an instance variable.

- When the car is instantiated, it's direction is not set (=null).
- When adding the first passenger check the direction of the car

  - If it is null, the car's direction is set to the passengers' direction and the passenger is added.
  - If it is non-null, compare the passenger's direction with the car's direction.

    - If directions match, add the passenger.
    - If no match, reject the passenger.
- When removing passengers, check if the car is now empty. If it is empty, change the direction to null.

That would allow you to reuse a car once the passengers have left.

Comment: Hi Hiran! Thank you so much for the quick response. To be honest, I'm new to optaplanner. Could you provide more information or maybe some code example? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Hiran! I haven't been able to solve this problem yet. Could you suggest how it can be implemented. For example, how can you check if the first object is initialized or not?